# C# Left Shift Operator

Tags: c#, filtering, bit-shift

There's a statement a co-worker of mine wrote which I don't completely understand. Unfortunately he's not available right now, so here it is (with modified names, we're working on a game in Unity).

```
private readonly int FRUIT_LAYERS =
          (1 << LayerMask.NameToLayer("Apple"))
        | (1 << LayerMask.NameToLayer("Banana"));
```

NameToLayer takes a string and returns an integer. I've always seen left shift operators used with the constant integer on the right side, not the left, and all the examples I'm finding via Google follow that approach. In this case, I think he's pushing Apple and Banana onto the same relative layer (which I'll use later for filtering). In the future there would be more "fruits" to filter by. Any brilliant stackoverflowers who can give me an explanation of what's happening on those lines?

Comment: I'd start by debugging this code, seeing what `NameToLayer` returns for each value, and seeing what each sub-expression returns.  Note that in this case you'll want to look at all values in binary, as they'll most likely make a lot more sense that way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your coworker is essentially using an `int` in place of a `bool[32]` to try to save on space. The block of code you show is analogous to

```
bool[] FRUIT_LAYERS = new bool[32];
FRUIT_LAYERS[LayerMask.NameToLayer("Apple")] = true;
FRUIT_LAYERS[LayerMask.NameToLayer("Banana")] = true;
```

You might want to consider a pattern more like this:

```
[Flags]
enum FruitLayers : int
{
    Apple = 1 << 0,
    Banana = 1 << 1,
    Kiwi = 1 << 2,
    ...
}

private readonly FruitLayers FRUIT_LAYERS = FruitLayers.Apple | FruitLayers.Banana;
```

Answer (score 7):

`1 << x` is essentially saying "give me a number where the (x+1)-th bit is one and the rest of the numbers are all zero.

`x | y` is a bitwise OR, so it will go through each bit from 1 to n and if that bit is one in either `x` or `y` then that bit will be one in the result, if not it will be zero.

So if `LayerMask.NameToLayer("Apple")` returns `2` and `LayerMask.NameToLayer("Banana")` returns `3` then `FRUIT_LAYERS` will be a number with the 3rd and 4th bits set, which is `1100` in binary, or 12 in base 10.

Answer (score 2):

The code is shifting the binary value 1 to the left, the number of binary places to shift is determined by the Apple and Banana, after both values are shifted the are ORed in a binary way

Example:
Assume apple returns 2 and banana returns 3 you get:
1 << 2 which is 0100 (that means 4 in decimal)
1 << 3 which is 1000 ( that means eight in decimal)

now 0100 bitwise or with 1000 is 1100 which means 12

Comment: ... `0100 + 1000 == 1100` which is 12.

Answer (score 2):

1 << n is basically an equivalent to 2<sup>n</sup>.